# Error request for member print which is of non-class type 'char'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, printing, char

Every time i try to run my print function it tells me:

```
SalesDB.cpp:61:19: error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘((SalesDB*)this)->SalesDB::salesPerson[i]’, which is of non-class type ‘char’
salesPerson[i].print();
               ^
```

I cant seem to figure out how to fix this. I included all the code that should be needed. Let me know if more is needed.

SalesDB.h

```
#ifndef SALESDB_H
#define SALESDB_H

#include "Seller.h"

class SalesDB
  {
  // Data members and method prototypes for the SalesDB class go here
  private:
    char salesPerson[30];
    int numSellers;
  public:
    SalesDB();
    SalesDB(const char*);
    void print();
  };

   #endif
```

SalesDB.cpp

```
#include "SalesDB.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;
           //default constructor
SalesDB::SalesDB()
{
numSellers = 0;
} 
         //constructor
SalesDB::SalesDB(const char* ptr)
{
 ifstream salesdb;
 salesdb.open("/location of file", ios::binary); //left out location on purpose
 if(!salesdb)
{
   cout<<"Error...";
   exit(1);
}
 else
{
 salesdb.read((char*) this, sizeof(SalesDB));
}
 salesdb.close();
}
     //print function
void SalesDB::print()
{
 for (int i=0; i < numSellers; i++)
  {
   cout << "Sales Database Listing " << i << ": " << endl;
   salesPerson[i].print();
  }
}
```

Seller.h

```
 class Seller
      {
        public:
          Seller();
          Seller(char[],double);
          char* getName();
          double getSalesTotal();
          void setSalesTotal(double);
          void print();

        private:
          char name[30]{};
          double salesTotal = 0;
      };

   #endif
```

Seller.cpp

```
#include "Seller.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::left;
using std::right;
using std::endl;
using std::setw;
using std::fixed;
using std::setprecision;

    //default constructor
Seller::Seller()
{
name[0]='\0';
}

    //Constructor
Seller::Seller(char newName[], double newTotal)
{
strcpy(name,newName);
salesTotal=newTotal;
}

   //getName
char* Seller::getName()
{
return name;
}
```

Any help as to why I am getting this error and how to fix it would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: salesPerson[i] is a char.  It has no print() member.

Answer (score 1):

`salesPerson` is an array of type `char`, therefore does not have a `print()` member.  Try instead:

```
Seller salesPerson[30];  // was char salesPerson[30]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
char salesPerson[30];
int numSellers;
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
std::vector<Seller> salesPerson;
```